# send attachment via SOAP in java

Tags: java, soap

I have an EJB standalone application which creates excel file upto 10 MB.

Now I want to send this files through SOAP.

I am not able understand where to begin with and what information I need to send the files to the end point.

Could you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry to say.. But I dont know how to begin with.. after I get an Idea what information i need I can try something

Comment: I did a quick search on Google and I found this page: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-attachment-example/